# React Cannot read property 'then' of undefined in componentDidMount

Tags: reactjs

I'm fetching using two APIs in componentDidMount. The second fetch needs ID from the first fetch to get fetched.

The first fetch works well, but when I want to map through it for the second fetch, I get an error : Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

A portion of Orders json is below:

```
{
    "orders": [
        {
            "deadline": 1563046159,
            "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.",
            "id": "83f007d6",
            "name": "Work order 83f007d6",
            "workerId": 1
        },
        {
            "deadline": 1562752687,
            "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.",
            "id": "cb23c526",
            "name": "Work order cb23c526",
            "workerId": 1
        },
]
}
```

And worker json is below:

```
{
    "worker": {
        "companyName": "Topiczoom",
        "email": "fstorie0@topiczoom.com",
        "id": 0,
        "image": "http://dummyimage.com/250x250.jpg/ccccff/000000",
        "name": "Frans Storie"
    }
}

class App extends Component {

constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state={
    ordersData: [],
    workersData:[]
  }
} 


  componentDidMount() {

    fetch("https://www.hatchways.io/api/assessment/work_orders")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({
          ordersData: data.orders
          });
          console.log(this.state.ordersData)
          .then(this.state.ordersData.map(order =>{
            console.log(this.state.ordersData)
           fetch(`https://www.hatchways.io/api/assessment/workers/${order.workerId}`)
            .then(result => result.json())
            .then( data2 =>{
              this.setState ({
                workersData : data2.worker
              })
            })
          }))
          console.log(this.state)
        })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
      }); 
  }
```

Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `.then` directly without `fetch` inside of `fetch` as you did.

You need a `callback` in `setState` to call another API based on state set from first API response,

```
fetch("https://www.hatchways.io/api/assessment/work_orders")
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        this.setState({
            ordersData: data.orders
        }, () => { //callback of setState, now here you can access state
            console.log(this.state.ordersData)
            this.state.ordersData.map(order => {
                console.log(this.state.ordersData)
                fetch(`https://www.hatchways.io/api/assessment/workers/${order.workerId}`)
                    .then(result => result.json())
                    .then(data2 => {
                        this.setState({
                            workersData: data2.worker
                        }, () => console.log(this.state))
                    })
            })
        });
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
    });
```

---

**Update**

To store all the records,

```
 () => { //callback of setState, now here you can access state
            console.log(this.state.ordersData)
            let workersData = [];
            this.state.ordersData.map(order => {
                console.log(this.state.ordersData)
                fetch(`https://www.hatchways.io/api/assessment/workers/${order.workerId}`)
                    .then(result => result.json())
                    .then(data2 => {
                        workersData.push(data2.worker)
                    })
            })
            this.setState({
                   workersData
            }, () => console.log(this.state))
        });
```

Comment: Right now, it does not store all workers data in the workersData in the array. It just stores one worker data. How can I fix it?

Comment: Still is an empty  array

Comment: ordersData: (20) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
workersData: []

Comment: worked with  workersData.push(data2.worker)       Thanks!!